# Start / Stop Fragment Programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I want to implement a feature toggle in OSGI, which means I want to start and stop bundles programmatically.

For plug-ins that's really easy:

```
Bundle plugin = //...
plugin.start();
plugin.stop();
```

For fragments it's not so easy. Stopping does not work at all, and if I use `uninstall()` the fragment is gone for good, and I'm not able to install it again, since I don't know the correct location for `BundleContext#installBundle(...)` (and looking at `Bundle#getLocation()`, neither does the fragment itself).

The problem I'm facing is I have a fragment contributing to some Eclipse extension points. Just stopping the host plug-in will not remove these services (for whatever reason). So I need to stop the fragment manually (or maybe clear that stupid Eclipse cache that keeps screwing applications up?).

So how can I install fragments at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments do not have their own life cycle. They are part of the life cycle of their host bundle. That means there is no way to start/stop them independently of the host.

If you need more background about bundles, fragments and life cycles, I advise you to read the OSGi specification, which can be downloaded from the http://osgi.org/ website.

Comment: Yes. If you need to programmatically start and stop some function, then you should not be using fragments to hold that function.

Comment: The problem is: if I stop the host plug-in, the fragment will still contribute its services.

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "services" because any OSGi service that is published by a bundle, will automatically disappear when that bundle is stopped. Maybe you're talking about some extender pattern (which can do pretty much anything in relation to the life cycle, so you have to take a look at its documentation or code)?

Comment: I added some more info to the question. The fragment is contributing to Eclipse extension points, and these are not removed when the host plug-in is.

Comment: If I remember correctly (and someone will surely correct me when I'm wrong) is that Eclipse's extension points do not activate themselves only when a bundle is in the "active" state (but also when "resolved" and maybe even when "installed") which means it is not really possible to make them go away by stopping the (host) bundle. I would even argue that that is a (serious) design flaw, but that's my personal opinion.