# Starting and Stopping Host Plug-ins

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

We have a standard Eclipse plug-in with the usual GUI elements, and since our applications don't have the same structure, the registration of these elements is done in a fragment, for example:

```
<fragment>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="popup:org.acme.menu>
            <command commandId="org.acme.command" style="push" />
        </menuContribution>
    </extension>
</fragment>
```

Now everything works as expected. The problem comes when stopping the host plug-in, because evidently the fragment gets not stopped as well, the menu in question stays populated, preference pages stay in the dialog, and so on.

I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773056/start-stop-fragment-programmatically) if I could just start and stop the fragment directly, but it was confirmed that you should not  (and in fact, cannot) do stuff like that to fragments.

Then I started to install / uninstall the fragment, which lead to some [bug in the PackageAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845863/packageadmin-closes-active-page).

As far as I can tell, it's fair game to put the registration of GUI elements in an fragment, and as far as I understand, the fragment's life cycle should be bound to the host, so it shouldn't contribute GUI elements when the host is stopped.

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension point declarations are available from any **installed** plugin or fragment regardless of whether or not they have been started. Stopping the host plugin won't make that menu declaration unavailable.

To achieve this you may need to register the menu contribution programmatically when the bundle starts and remove it when the bundle stops. This would probably mean using a separate plugin rather than a fragment as fragments don't have Activators.

Comment: Evidently extension points really do violate every OSGi rule ever, that's why they're deprecated and should not be used at all. I did not know that.